# Can i make a login form in Vb.net without using button like submit, login etc

Tags: vb.net

I want that. when the password match. It go to the next form or page. I doesn't want to click on button like submit, login etc. Can you please help me

Comment: But when i make a offline windows application then can i use this idea or not

Comment: That's not secure at all

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea.

You could perform the password check on the client. This means the code running in your web page must have access to the password: which means the user (eg. using DevTools and a little digging to network requests or the JS debugger) has access to the password which they can just copy. (Encryption just means they can copy the encrypted password to attack it offline).

You could sent each entered character to the server. This avoids the problems of doing the check on the client. But means you will be very sensitive to network latency. A few hundred milliseconds is enough to type multiple characters and you have to handle the cases of "the password was OK, but now they have added another character"; but you've already sent the redirect to the logged on page.